# Word: Applying a border to columned text

Tags: microsoft-word, format

Is it possible to put a border around text in columns such that the border goes around all of the columns?

When I tried to do this, the borders ended up going around the individual columns, breaking the text off from both the other columns and the preceding block of text into their own mini-boxes.

Is it possible to get it all into one unbroken box that surrounds multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

Could you just Insert a Shape? IE transparent filled box around your text.

Or even Free-form a border around the text that you want, using Insert Shapes.